# STM32: non-initialized variables?

Tags: variables, initialization, stm32, keil

using the uvision IDE for STM32 development, I want to have some timer variables not initialized at startup. I have tried:

```
volatile unsigned int system_time __attribute__((section(".noinit")));
```

and

```
__attribute__((zero_init)) volatile int system_timer;
```

but nothing seems to work. Following the hints from elswhere, I have additionally checked NoInit at options/target/IRAM1.
Still, the variables are set to zero after reset.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 4):

You need to follow these steps.
declare your variable as follows:

```
volatile unsigned int system_time __attribute__((section(".noinit"),zero_init));
```

Then you have to use a scatter file to declare the execution section with the NOINIT attribute and use it with the linker.
example scatter file:

```
LR_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00080000  {    ; load region size_region
   ER_IROM1 0x08000000 0x00080000  {  ; load address = execution address
      *.o (RESET, +First)
      *(InRoot$$Sections)
      .ANY (+RO)
   }
   RW_IRAM1 0x20000000 UNINIT 0x00000100  { ;no init section
      *(.noinit)
   }
   RW_IRAM2 0x20000100 0x0000FFF0  {                ;all other rw data
      .ANY(+RW +ZI)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to check the address of that variable from .MAP file and use the The *at* keyword

allows you to specify the address for uninitialized variables in your C source files. The

following example demonstrates how to locate several different variable types using the *at* keyword.for example......

```
struct link  {
  struct link idata *next;
  char        code  *test;
};

struct link idata list _at_ 0x40;     /* list at idata 0x40 */
char xdata text[256]   _at_ 0xE000;   /* array at xdata 0xE000 */
int xdata i1           _at_ 0x8000;   /* int at xdata 0x8000 */
char far ftext[256]    _at_ 0x02E000; /* array at xdata 0x03E000 */

void main ( void ) {
  link.next = (void *) 0;
  i1        = 0x1234;
  text [0]  = 'a';
  ftext[0]  = 'f';
}
```

I hope it helps for solving your problem.